# Why doesn't the update OLEDB query do nothing?

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, oledb

I'm using OLEDB in my program to update an excel sheet. The Execute returns 1 as row update count, but doesn't change nothing.
My code is as below:

```
public static void updateExcel(string sql, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con;
            OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();

            con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                            path +
                                            ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            con.Open();
            comm.Connection = con;
            comm.CommandText = sql;
            int y = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        } 

    }
```

And the calling is:

```
string sql = "update [Sh1$] set j = j + ' AAAA ' where a = '" + excelData.Rows[i]["a"].ToString() + "'";
EXCEL.updateExcel(sql, excelFile);
```

Does someone know what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your missing `HDR=YES` at the end of the Extended Properties on your connection.

Comment: I have tried it too...thanks!

Comment: try adding `con.Dispose();` after con.Close();

Comment: Still doesn't work. It doesn't update even 1 row.

Comment: So only one row changed?  Is the data that you are writing the same that is already in the sheet?

Comment: *Remove* that `catch{}` - if your query fails for any reason, you'll never know it because you throw the error away. Code like this *breaks* applications and makes debugging impossible

Comment: @jdweng: no row was changed, and the expected row exists.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am debugging it.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returned a one so one row was changed.  Try putting different data and see if the row changed.

Comment: @utor bad code is bad code. Remove that `try/catch`. Besides, what you wrote is vulnerable to SQL injection. What if the data contains multiple `'` characters? Or what if it's a number that ends up getting formatted using an unexpected format? What does the actual query string look like? Use parameterized queries, put the code in a `using` block and remove that `try/catch`

Comment: @utor in fact, that `ToString()` suggests you're trying to pass a number to the query, and yet, the `WHERE` clause is comparing a *string* enclosed in single quotes. Quoting in this case hides any formatting issues - a *lot* of countries use `,` as the decimal separator which means `3.5.ToString()` produces `3,5`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. the query is correct, and works in access.

Comment: The query clearly *doesn't* work. This is Excel, not Access anyway. Excel is not a database.  Post the *actual* query, ie the actual value in the `sql` variable, and an actual example of the data, especially the contents of the row you try to match, especially the contents of the first (`A`) column

Comment: this is the query: `update [Sh1$] set j = j + ' AAAA ' where a = '000043L6'`

Comment: @utor in any case, it's better to use a library like [Epplus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to create and manipulate Excel files directly, without going through Excel or the Jet driver. Epplus is a native .NET Standard library that works on any OS and doesn't care about the CPU architecture

Comment: @utor update the *question* and post the actual query and actual file contents there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the cells in the excel are empty. If so, this: `set j = j + ' AAAA '` won't work, because `j` is `NULL`.

In this case, this will be better:

`set j = ' AAAA '`

or

`set j = IIF(j IS NULL, ' AAAA ', j + ' AAAA ')`

Answer (score 1):

try re-writing with using:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"update [Sh1$] set j = j + ' AAAA ' where a = '" + excelData.Rows[i]["a"].ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //exception here
        }
        finally
        {
             conn.Close();
             conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The most important thing is to remove that `catch{}` and find out what the real error is. There's no need for that `finally` block either - `using` calls `Dispose()` which in turn calls `Close()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. ther is no error - it doesn't stop at the catch block.